# Take batches of records for each rank, then JOIN, then LIMIT 1 in postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, postgresql-10

I'm trying to improve the performance of my query. From the `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` I understand that my query considers too many `songs` records when I think it's not necessary.

There are three tables `artists(artist_id, score)`, `songs(song_id, artist_id)` and `listened(song_id)`.

My current query looks like this:

```
WITH artists_ranked AS (
    SELECT
      artist_id
      , rank() OVER (ORDER BY score ) rnk
    ORDER BY rnk ASC
),
    not_listened_songs AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM songs
      WHERE NOT EXISTS(
          SELECT 1
          FROM listened
          WHERE listened.song_id = songs.song_id) -- bad: I go through all songs
  ),
    shuffled_songs AS (
      SELECT *
      FROM artists_ranked
        JOIN not_listened_songs ON not_listened_songs.artist_id = artists_ranked.artist_id
      ORDER BY random() --bad: I shuffle all songs
  )
SELECT DISTINCT ON (artist_id) *
FROM shuffled_songs
LIMIT 1;
```

Ideally (at least in my mind), the query should follow these steps:

1. Rank the `artists` table by rating.
2. Take a batch of artists with the highest rating. Can be one or multiple artists.
3. Join with the table `songs`, but exclude already `listened` songs.
4. Now we want to pick one random song, by giving each of the artists equal chance.
   `ORDER BY random()`, `DISTINCT BY (artist_id)`, `LIMIT 1`
5. If there is such song, we stop and return it. Otherwise, take the next batch of artists (with closest lower rank) and repeat the steps.

   - To stop, either a song is returned (very likely in just after few iterations) or all artists have been considered.

Thank you.

Comment: Your current query doesn't do anything with the artist's score. I mean, the results of the query doesn't depend on the values of the artist's score. Please clarify how exactly you'd like to use the score.One possible variant: always consider the artist with the highest score first and pick one of his songs randomly. Once all of his songs have been listened, pick next (by score) artist and play his songs in a random order. If generalised, pick one random artist among top `N` artists, then pick one of his random songs

Comment: its impossible to write this query with the relations you provided. there needs to be a relationship between artists and songs

Comment: It's a simplified example and I messed it up. There is freedom to add wharever you need, or can be rewriten to fit the explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the problem in terms of relational algebra, not loops.

To get the songs not yet played join `artists` to `songs` where the `song_id` doesn't exist in `listened`. Order descending by score to get songs from the highest rated artists first, and then random to shuffle within each score. Limit to 1 record.

```
SELECT song_id
FROM artists a
JOIN songs s ON s.artist_id = a.artist_id
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT TRUE FROM listened l WHERE l.song_id = s.song_id)
ORDER BY score DESC, RANDOM()
LIMIT 1
```

> Can we give equal chance to each top score artist by considering equal amount of songs. Artists can have different number of songs. If there are 2 artists with top score and one has 100 songs, the other 1 song, then the probability to pick a song from the second artist is 0.01, but it should be 0.5

This ranks the songs not yet listened randomly for each artist, and then presents the final results sorted by the score descending & then by the song rank, which in effect interleaves random songs from all the artists at the same rank:

```
SELECT song_id
FROM artists a
NATURAL JOIN songs s 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT TRUE 
    FROM listened l 
    WHERE l.song_id = s.song_id
)
ORDER BY score DESC
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY artist_id ORDER BY RANDOM())
       , FIRST_VALUE(RANDOM()) OVER (PARTITION BY artist_id)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we give equal chance to each top score artist by considering equal amount of songs. Artists can have different number of songs. If there are 2 artists with top score and one has 100 songs, the other 1 song, then the probability to pick a song from the second artist is 0.01, but it should be 0.5. That's why use `DISTINCT BY`.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to use `LATERAL JOIN` to make engine look through artists one-by-one in the `score` order.

Add `artist_id` to the `listened` table to avoid extra join and limit search to just one artist at a time.

Add indexes to the tables. It is important to have these indexes.

```
artists (score, artist_id)
songs (artist_id, song_id)
listened (artist_id, song_id)
```

**Query**

```
SELECT
    artists.artist_id
    ,s.song_id
FROM
    artists
    INNER JOIN LATERAL
    (
        SELECT songs.song_id
        FROM songs
        WHERE
            songs.artist_id = artists.artist_id
            AND NOT EXISTS
            (
                SELECT 1
                FROM listened
                WHERE
                    listened.artist_id = songs.artist_id
                    -- limit listened songs to one artist
                    AND listened.song_id = songs.song_id
            )
        ORDER BY random()
        -- shuffle only songs of one artist
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS s ON true
ORDER BY artists.score ASC, random()
-- if there are several artists with the same score
-- pick one random artist among them
LIMIT 1;
```

The query will pick the top artist, play its songs randomly, pick next top artist, play his songs randomly, and so on.

This query should work fast when artists have songs to play and will become slower and slower and it goes through the list of top artists to lower ranked rows.

If the `score` is not unique, then `ORDER BY score LIMIT 1` would return one "random" row with the top score. It is not defined which artist would be picked. It is not strictly random, just not defined. It could change each time the query runs or stay the same. To make it truly random, just add `random()` explicitly.

With this addition the query will choose between several artists with the same top score with equal probability, regardless of how many songs they have.

---

You can extend the query to have "batches" of top `N` artists that it considers, not just the single top artist each time:

```
WITH
CTE
AS
(
    SELECT
        artists.artist_id
        ,s.song_id
    FROM
        artists
        INNER JOIN LATERAL
        (
            SELECT songs.song_id
            FROM songs
            WHERE
                songs.artist_id = artists.artist_id
                AND NOT EXISTS
                (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM listened
                    WHERE
                        listened.artist_id = songs.artist_id
                        -- limit listened songs to one artist
                        AND listened.song_id = songs.song_id
                )
            ORDER BY random()
            -- shuffle only songs of one artist
            LIMIT 1
        ) AS s ON true
    ORDER BY artists.score ASC
    LIMIT 5 -- pick top N artists, N = 5
)
SELECT
    artist_id
    ,song_id
FROM CTE
ORDER BY random() -- shuffle top N artists
LIMIT 1 -- pick one random artist out of top N
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I see only one limitation though. Can we make the number of artist in the batch to be calculated dynamically depending on how many artist share the highest score for the current iteration? For example, I might have listened all songs of the top artist, but there are N artist with score just one bellow  the top. I want to consider one song by each of them N artists when picking the next song to play.

Comment: @Granga, I didn't think that `score` is not unique. All you need is add `random()` to `ORDER BY`. I updated the answer